# email not send in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to send an email with spring boot that's way I'm setting this configuration in my aplication.properties :

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.host=xxxxx.hostgator.com
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.username=XXX@xxxx.com
spring.mail.password=XXXX
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.default-encoding=UTF-8
```

but the problem is when i test it with postman the request is always in the state "loading" :
[image]

when i test the function with an gmail account it works fin!
my fucntion :

```
public void sendPaimentEmail(String to, String subject, String text) {
      MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
      try {
          MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
          helper.setTo(to);
          helper.setSubject(subject);
          helper.setText(text, true);
          FileSystemResource imageSignature = new FileSystemResource(new File(this.pathToSaveFile2 + "logo.png"));

          if (null != imageSignature && imageSignature.exists()) {
             helper.addInline("logo", imageSignature);
           }

           FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(new File(this.pathToSaveFile2 + "historique.png"));
         helper.addAttachment("Invoice", file);
          this.emailSender.send(message);

    } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: any error Messages in the logfile?

Comment: i checked the console but no error!